# Populate different type form with jquery each not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to populate different type form on change option. My code goes below without error and I'm not getting expected result. Actually I want load all array value as checkbox but it always render last one and Unable to find What i'm doing wrong?

[image]

[Jquery]

```
$('select[name="scales"]').on('change',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var scale = $(this).val(); 
     switch(scale)
     {
        case 'shirtscale':
            var x = ['S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL','4XL','5XL','6XL','7XL','8XL','9XL','10XL'];
            $.each(x, function (index, value) {
                $("#xe").html("<input id='"+index+"' type='checkbox' value='"+value+"'>");
                console.log(value);
            });
            break;
        case 'ringscale':
            var x = ['3','3.5','4','4.5','5','5.5','6','6.5','7','7.5','8','8.5','9','9.5','10','10.5','11','11.5','12','12.5'];
            $.each(x, function (index, value) {
                $("#xe").html("<input id='"+index+"' type='checkbox' value='"+value+"'>");
                console.log(value);
            });         
            break;
        case 'shoescale':
            var x = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'];
            $.each(x, function (index, value) {
                $("#xe").html("<input id='"+index+"' type='checkbox' value='"+value+"'>");
                console.log(value);
            });             
            break;
        default:
    }
return false;
});
```

[View]

```
<select id="scales" name="scales">
    <option value="0">Choose Measurement Scale ...</option>
    <option value="shirtscale">Shirt</option>
    <option value="ringscale">Finger Ring</option>
    <option value="pantscale">Pant</option>
    <option value="waistscale">Waist</option>
    <option value="wristscale">Wrist</option>
    <option value="brascale">Bra</option>
</select>

<div id="xe"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `$("#xe").html(...` will overwrite the dom that is created for the previous element. Use `append`

```js
$('select[name="scales"]').on('change', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var scale = $(this).val();
  switch (scale) {
    case 'shirtscale':
      var x = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', '4XL', '5XL', '6XL', '7XL', '8XL', '9XL', '10XL'];
      appendVal(x);
      break;
    case 'ringscale':
      var x = ['3', '3.5', '4', '4.5', '5', '5.5', '6', '6.5', '7', '7.5', '8', '8.5', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5', '11', '11.5', '12', '12.5'];
      appendVal(x);
      break;
    case 'shoescale':
      var x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
      appendVal(x);
      break;
    default:
  }
  return false;
});

function appendVal(x) {
  // remove previous dom
  $("#xe").html('');
  let elem = ''
  $.each(x, function(index, value) {
    // create dom string taking each value from the arrat
    elem += `<input id='${index}' type='checkbox' value='${value}'><label for='${index}'>${value}</label>`
  });
  // append the final dom string
  $("#xe").append(elem);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="scales" name="scales">
  <option value="0">Choose Measurement Scale ...</option>
  <option value="shirtscale">Shirt</option>
  <option value="ringscale">Finger Ring</option>
  <option value="pantscale">Pant</option>
  <option value="waistscale">Waist</option>
  <option value="wristscale">Wrist</option>
  <option value="brascale">Bra</option>
</select>

<div id="xe"></div>
```